# How to import specs library

Tags: scala, classpath

How do I import specs library? I get the following error:

```
scala> import org.specs._
<console>:11: error: object specs is not a member of packa
ge org
       import org.specs._
              ^
```

I think it has to do with classpath, but I don't know how to fix it because I am new to scala.

In fact, I am actually trying to run tests in sbt, so it would be helpful if you could tell me how to import specs in sbt.

Comment: Could You please tell how your build.sbt looks like !

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava I was wondering if there is a way to pass the classpath as an argument when running sbt in interactive mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build.sbt should include

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "org.specs2"        %% "specs2"             % "2.3.12"             %    "test"
 )
}
```

and in your test.scala

```
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

class PlayerTest extends Specification {

   // test code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the dependency in build.sbt and compile it again then you can import spec2.